# Node.js slicing a very large buffer running out of memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance

I have a very large base64 encoded string that needs to be read into a byte (Uint8) array then split that byte array into chunks of a specified size them base64 encode those chunks separately. Using the function below works but calling .slice or .toString increases the memory on the heap with each call because (I believe) it's making a copy of the buffer. On particularly large base64Encoded strings the application will run out of space on the heap. What can be done to split this out into specified sizes and base64 encode them without running out of memory?

```
const process = function (reallyLargeBase64EncodedString, splitSize){

var theBuffer = Buffer.from(reallyLargeBase64EncodedString, 'base64');

//var tempBuffer = new Buffer(splitSize);
for (var start = 0; start < theBuffer.length; start += splitSize) {
    //for(var z = 0; z < splitSize; z++){
        //tempBuffer.writeUInt8( theBuffer[start+z],z);
    //}
    //var base64EncodedVal = tempBuffer.toString('base64');
    //var base64EncodedVal = theBuffer.buffer.toString('base64', start, start+splitSize);
    var base64EncodedVal = theBuffer.slice(start,start+splitSize).toString('base64'); 
    //do stuff with the base64 encoded value
}
```

};

Comment: No, [`slice` does not copy the memory](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_slice_start_end). `toString` does. What exactly is the "stuff" you're doing with the strings?

Comment: Right now inserting them into a database. Hmmm it's the toString that's the problem, perhaps changing that row from a string to a blob and just inserting the byte array directly will be better.

Comment: Is the database insertion asynchronous? You might want to make it sequential so that not all the strings are created in memory at once.

Comment: I was actually doing the insert with that last line, just took the database code out for the example.

Comment: If you have a "very large buffer" in Node.JS, then you're doing something wrong.

Comment: It's in json data coming back from a webservice call. Normally it's small but once in a while it's very large. (giggity)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would recommend using node's streaming interface to deal with something that large. If your base64 encoded string is coming from a file or a network request, you can pipe directly from the input into a base64 decode stream like [base64-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base64-stream).

In order to chunk the data and re-encode each chunk, you will have to write your own transform stream (stream that goes in between an input and an output). This will look something like

```
// NOTE: the following code has been tested in node 6.
// since it relies on the new Buffer api, it must be run in 5.10+
var Transform = require('stream').Transform;

class ChunkEncode extends Transform {
    constructor(options){
        super(options);
        this.splitSize = options.splitSize;
        this.buffer = Buffer.alloc(0);
    }

    _transform(chunk, encoding, cb){
        // chunk is a Buffer;
        this.buffer = Buffer.concat([this.buffer, chunk]);
        while (this.buffer.length > this.splitSize){
            let chunk = this.buffer.slice(0, this.splitSize);
            // Encode and write back to the stream.
            this.push(chunk.toString('base64')) 
            // throw in a newline for visibility.
            this.push('\n');
            // chop off `splitSize` from the start of our buffer.
            this.buffer = this.buffer.slice(this.splitSize);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you should be able to do something like

```
 var fs     = require('fs');
 var base64 = require('base64-stream');

 fs.createReadStream('./long-base64-string')
 .pipe(base64.decode())
 .pipe(new ChunkEncode({splitSize : 128}))
 .pipe(process.stdout)
```

this will log to standard out, but you could just as easily write to a file or a network stream. If you need to manipulate the data further, you could create a write stream, which would allow you to do something with each chunk of data as it comes in.

Comment: This is awesome and I really want to mark it as the answer but I solved the issue in a totally different way and the only reason your answer wasn't the one is because I didn't post ALL the code and I'm sorry for that. The real problem is that I'm a n00b when it comes to the async paradigm. This code was called from the result of a query the results from that query went to call an API then the code I posted and an insert for the b64 string. The initial database call hadn't ended yet and everything I was doing in there was getting thrown to the heap until it could be processed.

Comment: Don't worry about it. It is hard to tell which bits of code are going to be important in a question like this. Especially since the reason you asked the question is because you didn't have the answer :) I think the procedure in this case is to write your own answer. (pretty much that comment above) and mark it as correct.

Comment: I tested you answer too to see if it would save the heap size and it did.. not enough to stop the heap overflow but for loop got more than twice as far before barfing.

Comment: The `_transform` method does not call the callback and `_flush` should be also implemented to sent the remaining items in the buffer at the end of the stream.